# Unable to connect to the remote server when using HttpClient on an Azure Website

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, dotnet-httpclient

Our application is making HTTP requests with `HttpClient` to some websites. In local it always work, but for an unknown reason it fails in production.

Our application is an Azure Website.

We are getting the following error: `Unable to connect to the remote server`.

We have an IP Based SSL certificate, our IP address is not blacklisted anywhere. It was not happening before 3-4 days.

Depending on the URL we call, it sometimes work, sometimes not, we really don't get why.

**UPDATE**

It seems to only happen when we make requests to website hosted by GoDaddy, called their support and our IP address is not blocked.

Answer (score -1):

If you isolated that this is not a GoDaddy issue, I would contact support on Azure. It might be a tech issue or networking issue. They will help you isolate the source and fix it.

Comment: Thanks I just did it!